# How to choose a symbol to split in case of duplicate symbols

Tags: python, split

Suppose i have this string

```
string= 'Mynameis.Xyz.abc'
```

Im trying to split it to get a result like this:

```
result='Xyz.abc'
```

I have used the split command as follows

```
result =string.split('.')[1]
```

But what i get is

```
result='Xyz'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `'Mynameis.Xyz.abc'.split('.', 1)[-1]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
string= 'Mynameis.Xyz.abc'
new_string = string.split('.', 1)[1]
print(new_string)
```

OutPut:

```
'Xyz.abc'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either split on all dots, then join back the different parts except the first

```
spl = string.split(".")
result = ".".join(spl[1:])
print(result)  # Xyz.abc
```

Or split only on the first dot (`maxsplit`), then take second part

```
spl = string.split(".", maxsplit=1)
result = spl[1]
print(result)  # Xyz.abc
```